# Excel LOOKUP giving error even though data exists

Tags: excel, vlookup, lookup

I'm using the LOOKUP function with a data set.  I have the F column convert to number with 0 decimal point format for the cells but it's returning #N/A.  You can clearly see the number I put in is 5th from the bottom.  Tried with VLOOKUP with similar results.  Data was grabbed from sql server.

Would like to reference another cell from different sheet but even inputting in the actual number is not working right now.

[image]

Comment: some of your data is numbers stored as text and the some true numbers.  1.  `"1"<> 1` either make them all text or all numbers and then when you search use the same type. 2.  With Lookup the data must be sorted ascending.  You may want to look into Xlookup, Vlookup, or INDEX/MATCH which do not require the sorting for an exact match.

Comment: Have you tried match() and as Scott said some is stored as text - Excel shows you this by aligning text left and numbers right, so it is obvious...

Comment: @ScottCraner I believe they should be all numbers since I clicked on F column->format cells and selected the Number 0 Decimal places option or does that not do it?

Comment: No it does not.  If the numbers are stored as text they are text and number format will not change that.  There are many question/answers on this site that show various methods to changing them to numbers.

Comment: ok converting the column did the job working now.